# Android Multi-Screen Application on different devices

Tags: android

I want to create an application where it displays two different Activities which communicates with each other, and the two activities should run on 2 separate devices.

Ex: 12 Inch Tablet running the main app while a secondary tablet connected through USB to the original tablet should display the second screen.

Is there a way to build this without writing two different applications which communicates with each other, and just one app that can render a second activity in a separate screen connected by USB, even WiFi? And what would be the android sdk limitations on this?

Comment: I could see this as doable. Just have the apps communicating over wifi. Think about how multiplayer games work where things that happen on one screen need to appear on another (Obviously this isn't a game but just a way to look at it).

Comment: @C.Carter I was thinking if there's a way to do this without installing the same app in both the devices, but install it in one and presenting a second screen from the primary device, to the secondary device. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Maybe some kind of screen sharing? If the second tablet was in fact just a screen that connects via usb? Otherwise I'm not sure if it's possible without installing a second app